# How is typecasting an array different from typecasting an individual element?

Tags: java, type-casting

is the following code snippet:

```
           String[] str = {"Abc","Ghi","Def","Mno"};
           Object[] obj = str;
           String[] p = (String[]) obj;
```

same as :

```
          String[] str = {"Abc","Ghi","Def","Mno"};
          Object[] obj = str;
          String str1 = (String) obj[0];
          String str2 = (String) obj[1];
          String str3 = (String) obj[2];
          String str4 = (String) obj[3];
```

How is typecasting an array as in first code different from typecasting individual elements?Is it the same?

Answer (score 3):

For a start, in the first case you end up with a variable of type `String[]`, but in the second case you end up with four variables of type `String`.
What's the difference between an array and a bunch of variables? :)

Assuming you're more interested in the difference between the equivalent code producing an array:

```
Object[] obj = str;
String[] p = (String[]) obj;
```

and

```
Object[] obj = str;
String[] p = new String[] {
    (String)obj[0],
    (String)obj[1],
    (String)obj[2],
    (String)obj[3]};
```

the main differences are:

- The second code snippet creates a new array. If you were to do `str[2] = "blah";` after executing the first snippet, then `p[2]` would also contain "blah", because `p` and `str` are references to the same array. With the second snippet, `p[2]` would still contain `"Ghi"`.
- The second code snippet works regardless of the type of `str`. If `str` was actually created as:

  ```
  Object[] str = {"Abc","Ghi","Def","Mno"};
  ```

  then the first snippet would throw a `ClassCastException` because the object `obj` refers to is *not* a `String[]`. The second snippet would work fine provided all the *elements* are `String`s.
- The second snippet throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the array has less than four elements, and only copies the first four elements if it has more than four. However, you could easily write a version that would work for an arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where the types are checked:

```
       String[] p = (String[]) obj;
```

Here we check if `obj` really is a `String[]`. Having checked that, we know that every element in obj is a String.

```
      String str1 = (String) obj[0];
      String str2 = (String) obj[1];
      String str3 = (String) obj[2];
      String str4 = (String) obj[3];
```

Here, we check each element individually. We never check if obj is really a String[], and indeed this code will work if it isn't. Instead, we check each element individually to see if it is a String.